# I want to store one digit after floating point

Tags: java, floating-point

if I user entered 5.123 how can I store it in memory like 5.1
in java 
NOTE : I don't need to display it I want to (store) it in one digit after floating point only !!

ex:

6.334213 => 6.3

7.23947 => 7.2

100.123123 = > 100.1

0.123123 => 0.1

Comment: `floatValue = Float.valueOf(String.format("%.1f", floatValue));` try this.

Comment: use `BigDecimal`

Comment: Given that decimal digits are that important in your code, why not use BigDecimal?

Answer (score 1):

Great question. Here's an example. You can use the DecimalFormat object.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.util.*;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String []args) {

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##.#");
        df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);

        float number = 6.334213f;
        float fixedNumber = Float.parseFloat(df.format(number));
        System.out.println(number);
        System.out.println(fixedNumber);

    }
}
```

First, you create the DecimalFormat object and determine the format, as well as the rounding mode. Then, you can use the `format` function to convert it. However, this function returns a StringBuffer object (see it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)), so to store it in a float again, we need to convert it back to a float with `Float.parseFloat()`.

**UPDATE: (a better way)**

This is probably a more performant way to do this... multiply the number by its base (because it's a decimal (regular) number, the base is 10), raised to how many digits after the decimal point you want to keep.

So, in the example below, we want to truncate everything except 1 significant digit to the right of the '.', so we multiply by ten to the 1 (which is just 10), use the `Math.floor()` function to remove the decimal, and then divide again by the same number you multiplied by.

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String []args) {
        double number = 6.334213d;
        double fixedNumber = Math.floor(number * 10.0) / 10.0;
        System.out.println(fixedNumber);    // 6.3

        number = 6.334213d;
        fixedNumber = Math.floor(number * 1000.0) / 1000.0;
        System.out.println(fixedNumber);    // 6.334
    }
}
```

If we want to keep 3 digits after the '.', multiply by 10^3 (which is 1000), and then divide by the same number.

Comment: Multiplying+dividing by 10 is faster, but it also loses precision (if you care about that, which in this case author probably does not).

Comment: @bezmax that's true, but I think that's exactly what the question author wants (unless I missed something).

Comment: No, what I meant is that by performing a multiplication and division your are prone to bits overflowing because of how floating point calculation is done by CPU. See this example: https://ideone.com/pxlYoH

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there isn’t a good way to do this, so I tend to do this: Multiply by ten, then round it, then divide it by ten.

Comment: float a,x;
  a = scan.nextFloat();
  x = Math.round(a*10) / 10;
  System.out.println(x);

Comment: output => 5.0 but I need 5.1

Comment: @Adham you are aware that you should divide by `10f` (or 10.0 for double)? `51 / 10` is integer division, result is `int` 5. Also note that `0.1 + 0.2 != 0.3`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.#");
```

For more details on rounding off double values, please read [this tutorial by Mkyong.com](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-round-double-float-value-to-2-decimal-points-in-java/).